# How Can I extract the ID, Stype and first Statustime from each result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query result coming from the 3 tables and the Query I wrote.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8PWV.png)
So I wanted to get :

```
1st 67807 order and  2017-04-07 16:28:04.100
2nd I wanted 19859 Quote 2017-02-27 10:04:55.240
```

like wise from all results , how can I write the query , the query that brings result is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT qstatus AS Status, 
               quoteid AS ID, 
               'Quote' AS stype, 
               statusdescription, 
               statustime 
        FROM   quotestatus 
        WHERE  quoteid IN (SELECT quoteid 
                           FROM   quotes 
                           WHERE  customerid = 1 
                                  AND isseen = 0) 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT ostatus AS Status, 
               orderid AS ID, 
               'Order' AS stype, 
               statusdescription, 
               statustime 
        FROM   orderstatus 
        WHERE  orderid IN(SELECT orderid 
                          FROM   orders 
                          WHERE  customerid = 1 
                                 AND isseen = 0) 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT istatus   AS Status, 
               invoiceid AS ID, 
               'Invoice' AS stype, 
               statusdescription, 
               statustime 
        FROM   invoicestatus 
        WHERE  invoiceid IN (SELECT invoiceid 
                             FROM   invoices 
                             WHERE  customerid = 1 
                                    AND isseen = 0)) AS unionall 
ORDER  BY statustime DESC 

I have Quote, Invoice and Order table and when any change happens I wanted to notify them.
```

Comment: It will help to format the sql better so its readable and syntactically correct. Also sample data will be great too!

Comment: Post some sample data. Format your queries. Your question is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following, create the partition and select all with row number one.

```
 SELECT
      *
    FROM (SELECT
      ID,
      stype,
      statustime,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, stype ORDER BY statustime DESC) AS rownum
    FROM (SELECT
      qStatus AS Status,
      quoteID AS ID,
      'Quote' AS stype,
      statusDescription,
      statustime
    FROM QuoteStatus
    WHERE quoteID IN (SELECT
      quoteID
    FROM Quotes
    WHERE customerID = 1
    AND IsSeen = 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      oStatus AS Status,
      orderID AS ID,
      'Order' AS stype,
      statusDescription,
      statustime
    FROM OrderStatus
    WHERE orderID IN (SELECT
      orderID
    FROM Orders
    WHERE customerID = 1
    AND IsSeen = 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      iStatus AS Status,
      invoiceID AS ID,
      'Invoice' AS stype,
      statusDescription,
      statustime
    FROM InvoiceStatus
    WHERE invoiceID IN (SELECT
      invoiceId
    FROM Invoices
    WHERE customerID = 1
    AND IsSeen = 0)) AS unionall) AS ty
    WHERE rownum = 1
    ORDER BY statustime DESC;
```